# how to run ADB command on tv box via wifi?

Tags: android, adb, tvbox

I have a tv box device connected to TV, i need to run the following commands using ADB on my device

```
1. adb connect xxx.xxx.x.x : connected to device wirelessly success 
2. adb reboot recovery : success
3. now i need to click Apply update from ADB : success
Then a message appear on the tv: now send the package you want to apply
```

From my adb CMD i type: **adb sideload filename.zip** but the device becames offline after step 3 above.
how can i keep the device connected to my ADB even if i click apply update from ADB?

note that the cable Male to Male usb doesnt work and not catching my tv box

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try a different approach. If your device has enough cache memory, you can try to copy your ota.zip file inside it. Try loading the
filename.zip to /cache/.

```
adb connect xxx.xxx.x.x
adb push filename.zip /cache/filename.zip
```

Then, use the commandline

```
adb reboot recovery --update_package=/cache/filename.zip
```

The device will reboot into recovery mode and apply the OTA directly.

Comment: the command `adb reboot recovery --update_package=/cache/filename.zip` show only the recovery screen so i choose apply update from EXT and choose sdcard or udisk but no file or directory

Comment: note that i pushed the file into `/storage/emulated/0` because `/cache` show me **permission denied**